# Cryptographic requirements for random numbers on substrate chain

Tags: substrate-node, cryptography, randomness

As far as I know, one of the possibilities to generate random numbers within a substrate chain is by using the [pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/pallet_insecure_randomness_collective_flip/index.html). However, the documentation explicitly states that is not recommended for use in production:

*"The produced values do not fulfill the cryptographic requirements for random numbers. Should not be used for high-stake production use-cases."*

I'm wondering what those cryptographic requirements are and if there are any other alternatives to produce random (or pseudo-random) numbers on a substrate chain.